# Chrome Extension - javascript return results to popup HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension and I cannot figure out how to pass the javascript response returned in `popup.js` back to `popup.html` (so the user can see the results). I tried adding `<div id="tabs"> </div>` into `popup.html` thinking that would dynamically bring back `function(tabs)` results but it does not, greatly appreciate any insights.

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="myButton.css">
  </head>
  <body style="background-color:Gray;">
     <a href="#" class="myButton">Scan</a>
     <script src=popup.js></script>
     <div id="tabs"> </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    currentWindow: true
}, function(tabs) {
    var tabURL = tabs[0].url;
    var api = "https://api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com..."
    console.log(tabURL);
    console.log(api)
    userdata = {"url":tabURL}
    console.log(userdata)
    
    fetch(api, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(userdata),
    })
   .then((resp) => resp.json())
   .then(function(response) {
    console.info('fetch()', response);
    return response;
}); 
});
```

Comment: Did you see your response in the console log from the popup HTML? Just right-click on the popup then you can inspect it to check.

Comment: Yes, I can see the response in the console log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert Elements into popup.html with popup.js.

e.g.

```
function addSpan(response) {
        let tabDiv = document.getElementById('tabs');
        let newSpan = document.createElement('span');
        newSpan.innerText = "Test123".
        // newSpan.innerText = response;
    
        tabDiv.append(newSpan);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lansky - when I add this function to popup.js I am not seeing the "Test123". Do I need to explicitly call the addSpan function?

Comment: Yes, if you want to test it just add addSpan("Test123") or something like that to your popup.js. 

I packed it inside a function so you can call it at the end of your code instead of 
"return response"
you put
addSpan(response);